# Error, pygame.image.load, unable to resolve

Tags: pygame

To start, this seems to be a common issue for folks but the resolves which have helped them have been little help to myself. Preliminaries, I am running Raspbian w/Pixel on the RaspberryPi3B. I have read all relevant pygame documentation on the matter along with other resources. Here is the link to the doc; https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load .

I have re-installed everything using the shell:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mercurial 

$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

$ cd pygame

$ sudo apt-get install libsdl-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-
mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev 

$ sudo apt-get install libsmpeg-dev libportmidi-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev

$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-numpy

$ python3 setup.py build 
$ sudo python3 setup.py install
```

So now starts the fun..
I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/pi/Python_Code/Revenge of the Morning Wood.py", line 19, in
>   
>       lumberJack = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/Python_Code/Revenge_of_the_Morning_wood/lumberJack.png')
>
> pygame.error: Couldn't open
>   /home/pi/Python_Code/Revenge_of_the_Morning_wood/lumberJack.png

Code up to the point of error:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Revenge of the Morning Wood")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

lumberJack = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/Python_Code/Revenge_of_the_Morning_wood/lumberJack.png'

def lumberJack(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(lumberJack,(x,y))

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)
```

It won't even show an uncompressed .bmp file. I've tried all file extensions and all combination of file locations in relation to source code/image/pygame_module.

`pygame.image.get_extended()` initially popped an error in python shell but after the installation detailed above now returns a value of "1".

Comment: That error means it could not open that image file. Are you sure it's in the correct directory (and/or the correct filename)?

Comment: I've tried all combinations of directories. My first inclination was to think pygame has been corrupted but the second install from a different source ruled that out. I've tried several images with several different extensions. I'll play with it some more tonight. You are most likely correct that it's a problem in the program navigating through directories, I just can seem to resolve it.

Comment: Try editing your question with the file structure of your project.

Comment: I'll update it tonight.

Comment: Just a random shot in the dark but could it be a capitalization error in your directory: `Revenge_of_the_Morning_wood` --> `Revenge_of_the_Morning_Wood`. Linux is picky about these things. Great game title btw! :)

Comment: I kept consistency with regard to case sensitivity in all areas. The file, folder, and pathway are all capitalized in the same manor. But for the sake of ruling everything it I'll have it all lowercase when I get home and report back along with file pathways.

Answer (score 0):

The long awaited resolve! I removed the image extension entirely. Ensuring the image was in the pygame directory:

```
lumber_Jack = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pygame/lumberJack')
```

This was actual mentioned in the documentation I included earlier but I overlooked it. https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load :

> Pygame will automatically determine the image type (e.g., GIF or bitmap) and create a new Surface object from the data. In some cases it will need to know the file extension (e.g., GIF images should end in ”.gif”).

- For those of you wondering why I changed the name of my variable. I also noticed an issue with my variable lumberjack sharing the same name as my lumberjack function but this did not contribute to the issue. For anyone else having this issue just leave off the .PNG, .BMP, JPG, etc.